# Ctrl + X not decrementing number by specified amount

Tags: vim

I have the following line of text:

```
Foo bar 15 test.
```

My cursor is on the F at the start of the line, and I am in normal mode. I want to decrement 15 by 10, so my line reads like so:

```
Foo bar 5 test.
```

Apparantly, I should therefore, without moving my cursor, be able to type `10` and then hold down `Control` and type `x`. This is however only decrementing my number by 1, as opposed to 10.

Is there maybe an add on that vim needs to be able to do this, or do I need to change a setting in vim for this to work. I am using vim without the GUI running on Ubuntu 12.04 Server via Putty.

My version of vim is as follows:

> :version VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May  4 2012
>   04:09:27) Included patches: 1-429 Modified by
>   pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org Compiled by buildd@ Huge
>   version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
>   +arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent -clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments +conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs
>   -dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds
>   +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape +mouse_dec +mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +mouse_urxvt +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg +path_extra -perl
>   +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile +python -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl
>   +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save    system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
>        user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
>         user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"   fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim" Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
>   -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim       -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O 1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're holding down Control? Or are you just deleting the character `5` with `x`? What happens when you do `10<C-A>` instead?

Comment: @glts I am holding down control yes. when I use `A` as opposed to `x` I increment by one. It works properly when my cursor is actually on the number, but my understanding is that this should work even if my cursor is at the start of the line, is this correct?

Comment: You are probably using *vi*, or Vim in compatible mode. It doesn't support using a count with `<C-A>`/`<C-X>`. Upgrade to a proper Vim.

Comment: I've added the response from running the version command to my question, I don't see anything about compatibility mode and it is definitely full vim.

Comment: What does `:set compatible?` say? If it's `compatible`, do `:set nocp` and try `10<C-X>` again.

Comment: `:set compatible` literally returns nothing!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30647/discussion-between-glts-and-jmk)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably running Vim in *compatible* mode.

The command

```
:set nocompatible
```

puts Vim in *nocompatible* mode and magically enables various useful features not present in *vi*, including using a count with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

If you always want to start Vim in nocompatible mode (which is ***strongly*** recommended), create a basic vimrc file in your home directory with the following contents.

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin indent on
```

If you're new to Vim and don't know what a vimrc file is, read the introduction in the help at [`:h vimrc-intro`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#vimrc-intro).